# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Strings

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, kotlin, apache-camel

I searched similar questions on StackOverflow and cannot find anything.

My `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dmytro-camel-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.31</kotlin.version>
        <camel.version>2.23.1</camel.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <google-cloud.version>1.92.0</google-cloud.version>
        <google-firestore.version>1.22.0</google-firestore.version>

        <javax-jaxb.version>2.2.11</javax-jaxb.version>
        <javax-activation.version>1.1.1</javax-activation.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Kotlin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-google-pubsub-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-zipfile</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- GCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>${google-cloud.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
            <version>${google-firestore.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDK >=10 doesn't bundle JAXB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax-jaxb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>${javax-activation.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-java-parameters</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <!-- Spring compiler plugin will automatically open relevant classes and members for Spring AOP support. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html -->
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <jvmTarget>${jdk.version}</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <!-- Needed by the Spring compiler plugin. -->
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ci</id>

            <properties>
                <revision>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</revision>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I got the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/api/client/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Strings   at
>   org.apache.camel.component.google.pubsub.GooglePubsubEndpoint.afterPropertiesSet(GooglePubsubEndpoint.java:87)
>   ~[camel-google-pubsub-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]  at
>   org.apache.camel.component.google.pubsub.GooglePubsubEndpoint.createConsumer(GooglePubsubEndpoint.java:109)
>   ~[camel-google-pubsub-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]  at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.EventDrivenConsumerRoute.addServices(EventDrivenConsumerRoute.java:69)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRoute.onStartingServices(DefaultRoute.java:107)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:172)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:145)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3953)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3860)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3646)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3489)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$4.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3248)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$4.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3244)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3267)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3244)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:72)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3160)
>   ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]   at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:133)
>   ~[camel-spring-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]     at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:174)
>   ~[camel-spring-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:896)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   com.stackoverflow.example.ExampleAppKt.main(ExampleApp.kt:13)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Strings   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_202-release]   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_202-release]   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_202-release]   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_202-release]   ... 33 common frames omitted

How to resolve it? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Most issues of this type out there seem to point at the version of guava that is being pulled down... Do a mvn dependency:tree to see if there are dependency conflicts or just try adding a guava dependency (21.0) to see if it addresses you issue..

Comment: Can you try removing *<version>${camel.version}</version>* . Actually, spring boot is smart enough to configure version automatically.

Comment: @AvijitBarua It doesn't help because if I remove it, dependency cannot be resolved at all.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi Can you replace version  `<camel.version>2.23.1</camel.version>` to `<version>2.17.0</version>`?

Comment: @AvijitBarua pubsub-starter was added in version 2.19.2, so I cannot use 2.17.0. I degraded camel to 2.19.2 but it didn't help.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi I create a project like your `pom.xml` and project is running well. Can you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written `pom.xml` like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Camel -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-google-pubsub-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-zipfile</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- GCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.86.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And project is running well. Can you check please?

Comment: It didn't resolve my problem per se BUT it helped to debug it and solved 90% of my issue.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi would be useful , if you remember how you solved this. I am struggling with this and seems like an open issue here https://github.com/awslabs/rds-data-api-client-library-java/issues/5

Comment: @TheAshwaniK I think one of my colleagues created the package that included the missing bit in the end. Ideally, if you get these sorts of errors, upgrade to Camel 3.X.X

Another alternative, if neither of these would work for you, is to downgrade to versions that have this package included (it might be the worst solution if you care about security and are aware of existing vulnerabilities in packages).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the Guava dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This might resolve the issue.